# In Javascript, "" + 8.1 works fine, giving "8.1", but "" + 8.0 gives "8". How to make it give "8.0"?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript (trying in Firefox 4)

```
"" + 8.1
```

gives `"8.1"` (a string).  But

```
"" + 8.0
```

gives `"8"` (also a string), but is there a way to make it give `"8.0"` instead like it did for `8.1`?

Comment: Do you want to display a certain number of decimal places?  Is `"8.0"` not an option?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format) it might help you out alot.

Comment: ??? I do want `"8.0"`  That's what I wanted in the first place

Comment: Sorry, I meant using the string `"8.0"` not `8.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [toFixed](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html) function:

```
"" + (8).toFixed(1)
```

Comment: since .toFixed() returns a string anyway, you don't even need to add it to the empty string.

Comment: If you need more digits of precision but still want to strip trailing zeros, you could do something like `(8.5).toFixed(5).replace(/(.\d+?)0*$/, "$1")`

Answer (score 1):

You need a proper `printf` style extension for Javascript if you want to show numbers with a particular precision - you can't do it with plain type coercion.

Search for "javascript printf" here and on Google - there's plenty of suitable references.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has internal type convertion (called [loose typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing)) so that it converts `8.0` to `8` by default. Javascript has no separate datatypes for float numbers and integers like other languages. It has just the type `Number`. You can print numbers using `printf` (e.g. from a [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sprintf) or you can convert the Number to a string with fixed width: `(8).toFixed(1)` which creates a string, so you don't have to use `"" + ...`

Answer (score -1):

This will work also:

8 + 0.1 + ""

Comment: He wants the string "8.0" as a result (as opposed to "8").